# Do Dividend Stocks Offer Better Resilience During Market P/E Contraction?

Tags: equities, dividends

I'm interested in how stocks with higher dividend yields perform during periods of market P/E contraction. Specifically, I've observed that (so far I am working on the models):

**Market-wide P/E Contraction:** During times when average P/E ratios are decreasing, most stocks in the market tend to decline in value by a similar percentage, regardless of their individual valuations.

**Resilience of Dividend Payments:** Despite this general contraction, dividend-paying stocks continue to make their dividend payments.

So my key question is: Does the ongoing payment of dividends offer an advantage in terms of total returns during market P/E contractions?

I'm looking for both theoretical insights and empirical data that can shed light on this particular behavior of dividend stocks during P/E contraction periods.

Thank you for your expertise.